# How can I pick out the odd numbers and even numbers from a given array and then store them in another array?

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

How can I pick out the odd numbers and even numbers from a given array and then store them in another array? The flow is: the odd numbers will go to the `odd[]` array while the even numbers will go to the `even[]` array??

Here's my code, I'm not sure if this is correct since it somewhat stores and prints a mix of zeros and even numbers, no presence of odd numbers.....

```java
int[] num = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16};

int[] odd = new int[10];
int[] even = new int[10];

for (int i = 0; i < num.length; i++) {  // For odd numbers
    if (num[i] % 2 != 0) {
        num[i] = odd[i];
    }
    System.out.println(num[i] + " ");
}

for (int j = 0; j < num.length; j++) {  // For even numbers
    if (num[j] % 2 == 0) {
        num[j] = even[j];
    }
    System.out.println(num[j] + " ");
}
```

Comment: do a new counter variable for the odd and even elements starting by zero assigning it to this indice at the new arrays and increment always when you have assigned a odd or even number these counters

Comment: are you supposed to change num or just get numbers from num?

Comment: @depperm, I'll just get the numbers from the num

Comment: Your array element assignments are the wrong way. You want to to store the found even/odd number in your `odd` and `even` arrays and not modify your original `num` array. So it should be `odd[i] = num[i];`

Comment: is the array always a positive sequence like that? Or numbers can be anything?

Comment: @OHGODSPIDERS you would then only assign every second value in this odd and even array

Comment: @OHGODSPIDERS, ohhhh, so its the other way around...

Comment: do two indice variables *int oddIndice = 0* *int evenIndice = 0*. Then if it is even (checking by your condition) do ```even[evenIndice] = num[i]; evenIndice ++;```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do all that in one loop - that would be way faster. To know the correct position to put the number in, add extra counter for each array.

#### Your kind of approach

```java
int[] num = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16};
int[] odd = new int[10];
int[] even = new int[10];
int oddPos = 0;
int evenPos = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < num.length; i++) {
    if (num[i] % 2 == 0) {
        even[evenPos] = num[i];
        evenPos++;
    } else {
        odd[oddPos] = num[i];
        oddPos++;
    }
}
```

However this would not be the best solution as you (in most cases) cannot determine the length of `odd` and `even` arrays beforehand. Then you should use either arraylists or count the values of each or something else.

#### More dynamic approach

As stated before - you need to determine the size of the arrays at first

```java
int[] num = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16};
int oddCount = 0, evenCount = 0;
int oddPos = 0, evenPos = 0;
//get the count of each type
for (int i = 0; i < num.length; i++) {
    if (num[i] % 2 == 0)
        oddCount++;
    else
        evenCount++;
}
//define arrays in correct sizes
int[] odd = new int[oddCount];
int[] even = new int[evenCount];
//put values in arrays
for (int i = 0; i < num.length; i++) {
    if (num[i] % 2 == 0) {
        even[evenPos] = num[i];
        evenPos++;
    } else {
        odd[oddPos] = num[i];
        oddPos++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Very well explained sir!!! Thank you very much for the guide!! Especially on the dynamic approach on how to determine the size of the arrays! Thank you so much!!!

Answer (score 2):

the approach for detecting `odd` and `even` numbers is correct, But I think the problem with the code you wrote is that the length of `odd` and `even` arrays, isn't determinant. so for this matter, I suggest using `ArrayList<Integer>`, let's say you get the array in a function input, and want arrays in the output (I'll mix the arrays in the output for better performance. but separating the functions for each list extracting is also ok depending on what you're going to do with them).

#### Solution

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class Test {
    public static Integer[][] separateOddnEven(int[] input) {
        Integer[][] output = new Integer[2][];
        List<Integer> odds = new ArrayList<>();
        List<Integer> evens = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < input.length; ++i) {
            int temp = input[i];
            if (temp % 2 == 0)
                evens.add(temp);
            else
                odds.add(temp);
        }
        // alternative is to use these Arraylists directly
        output[0] = new Integer[odds.size()];
        output[1] = new Integer[evens.size()];
        output[0] = odds.toArray(output[0]);
        output[1] = evens.toArray(output[1]);
        return output; // index 0 has odd numbers and index 1 has even numbers.
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] input = {0, 21, 24, 22, 14, 15, 16, 18};
        Integer[][] output = separateOddnEven(input);
        System.out.println("odd numbers :");
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(output[0]));
        System.out.println("even numbers :");
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(output[1]));
    }
}
```

#### output :

```
odd numbers :
[21, 15]
even numbers :
[0, 24, 22, 14, 16, 18]
```

Answer (score 1):

*in lambda (3 lines)*

```java
int[] nums = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16};
```

separate even and odd `nums` with `partitioningBy`:

```java
Map<Boolean, List<Integer>> map = IntStream.of(nums)
        .boxed().collect(partitioningBy(n -> (n & 1) == 0));
```

…and transform the resulting `List<Integer>` for even and odd to `int[]`:

```java
int[] even = map.get(true).stream().mapToInt(i -> i).toArray();
int[] odd = map.get(false).stream().mapToInt(i -> i).toArray();

System.out.println("even numbers: " + Arrays.toString(even));
System.out.println("odd numbers:  " + Arrays.toString(odd));
```

```
even numbers: [2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16]
odd numbers:  [1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can collect a 2d array with two rows: *even* and *odd* as follows:

```java
int[] num = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16};
```

```java
// a 2d array of two rows: even and odd
int[][] arr = new int[2][];
// process a 1d array and fill a 2d array
Arrays.stream(num).boxed()
        // Map<Integer,List<Integer>>
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                // key: 0 - even, 1 - odd
                n -> n % 2,
                // value - a list of one
                // element, i.e. number
                n -> new ArrayList<>(List.of(n)),
                // merge duplicates
                (list1, list2) -> {
                    list1.addAll(list2);
                    return list1;
                }))
        // fill the rows of a 2d array: even and odd
        .forEach((key, value) -> arr[key] = value.stream()
                .mapToInt(Integer::intValue).toArray());
```

```java
// output
System.out.println("Even: " + Arrays.toString(arr[0]));
// Even: [2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16]
System.out.println("Odd: " + Arrays.toString(arr[1]));
// Odd: [1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15]
```